# Enviar variable a un modal

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Que tal, estoy intentando enviar una variable de index.php a un modal sin recargar la pagina en absoluto, ya que previamente se llenan algunos formularios entonces no puedo simplemente enviar por get y recargar la pagina (lo cual seria muy facil)

```
var fech = $('#input').val();
```

Envio de index.php a un modal que esta **incluido en index.php**, este modal lo tengo en un archivo diferente modal.php incluido en el mismo index.php como se menciona anteriormente

```
include("modal.php");
```

ya probe con ajax, jquery etc pero simplemente no puedo obtener el valor (este scritp esta dentro de index.php)

```
<script>
  $("#btnsend").click(function(){
    var fech = $('#input').val();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "modal.php",
      data: { dato: fech }
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
       alert( "Data Saved: " + fech);
     });
  });
</script>
```

esta fue mi ultima prueba, se imprime el valor en el alert con exito pero no se ve en el modal.

ya en modal.php asi es como obtengo dicha variable de manera normal pero no se visualiza.

```
echo $vr2=$_POST["dato"];
```

Comment: ¿El resultado final del modal e `index.php` es una sola página?

Comment: eso es correcto!

Comment: ¿No puedes poner el valor como un `input hidden` y capturar la variable en el mismo evento donde lanzas el modal?

Comment: ¿En modal.php solo tienes esa linea de código?

Comment: no, para nada, obviemos que esta el modal y sus contenedores en html

Comment: Podrías subir el código completo?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cambiar el `method:"POST"` por `type: "POST"`, otra opción es contatenar la url con los parámetros

`<script>
  $("#btnsend").click(function(){
    var fech = $('#input').val();
    var direccion = "modal.php"+"?dato="+fech;
    $.ajax({
      url: direccion,
      type:"POST"
      data: {}
    })
    .done(function(msg) {
       alert( "Data Saved: " + fech);
     });
  });
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Inmagino que en el modal.php tienes algo de codigo php, es decir, algunas validaciones o calculos que deseas hacer con las variables que estas recibiendo, Si no quires recargar la pagina, en vez de hacer:
`<?php include "modal.php"; ?>`

Debes cargar el modal.php con ajax y enviar los datos ya sea por GET

```
$('#div_modal').load('modal.php?variable=1');
```

o por POST:

```
var fech = $('#input').val();
$.ajax({
  url: "modal.php",
  type:"POST",
  data: {"valor":fech}
})
.done(function(r) {
   $('#div_modal').html(r);
 });
```

en el modal debes tener algo como esto:

```
<div class="modal">
  <input type="text" value="<?php print $_POST['variable']; ?>"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El modal.php lo tienes incluido en el index.php de esta manera?

```
<?php include "modal.php"; ?>
```

O lo estas invocando mediante ajax con:

```
$('#div_modal').load('modal.php');
```

Espero tu respuesta para ayudarte.

Comment: De la primer forma, con include